# native python3 fails to import sqlite3 on ubuntu focal

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I recently installed ubuntu focal on my laptop and running `ipython` based on the python3 (3.8.5) provided by the system produces the following warning:

`UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved`

Digging further I found that the problem came from the import of sqlite3 in python which produces the following error:

`ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr`

I read some posts related to this kind of error but all were about python that the user installed on their own. Here I am dealing with a python provided by the system and I do not want to install a python from scratch. Would you know what is wrong ?

Comment: Are you using a python virtual environment?

Comment: yes. But it also fails when using the native python outside my env

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I reference Robin's answer and check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and find it's not empty.

After running `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the Bash, or `unsetenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the C-Shell, the `ipython` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My experience maybe helpful:

1. check the dynamic library linked by sqlite3

   ldd /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
   I found that it linked wrong .so library.
2. reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH and reinstall sqlite3

Comment: sorry - I wasn't able to figure out what you meant. The result of the above command 1 is:
`linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff82f50000)
 libsqlite3.so.0 => /home/soumi/anaconda3/envs/env_namd/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/../../libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fbff660e000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbff6407000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbff6401000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbff63de000)
`
However, i'm not sure how to reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH...

Comment: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH returns nothing - it seems like there's no variable called that..